# Sitecore ASP.NET MVC Glimpse not showing Views and Timeline details

Tags: sitecore, sitecore8, glimpse

I've installed the Glimpse and Sitecore Glimpse for Sitecore 8.1 and configured per glimpse documentation.

Unfortunately I'm not seeing:

1. Any Views details in Views Tab
2. All action and controllers in Timeline

[image]

Any help will be much appreciated

Under Trace Tab I can see log below:

*Failed to load Sitecore Analytics Glimpse data - Object reference not set to an instance of an object.*

Comment: Check that the Sitecore Glimpse binaries are in your bin folder. They are: `Sitecore.Glimpse.Core.dll`, `Sitecore.Glimpse.dll` and `Sitecore.Glimpse.Infrastructure.dll`

Comment: yep all there. any special config or step required for sitecore glimpse?